# How to make an object persist after a loop in Scala?

Tags: scala, for-loop, persistence

Let's say I have a for loop that in each iteration creates an object and does something, for example:

```
def someMethod() {
    for( x <- e) {
      if( x == 1)  val z = 4
      else val z = 5
    }
    z
}
```

but that doesn't work because "z" does not go outside of the for loop. If I want that to work I have to do it this way:

```
def someMethod() {
var z = 0
    for( x <- e) {
      if( x == 1) z = 4
      else z = 5
    }
    z
}
```

But I feel it's not the correct workaround. How to make the object (z in this example) persist out of the for loop?

Comment: Hey, appreciate all the answers. I've provided an example that's way too simplified (my bad) but I've chosen an answe that fits my needs the best.
Thank you all for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a for comprehension try

```
for (x <- e; z = if (x == 1) 4 else 5) yield z
```

where (immutable) value with label `z` gets the result from the if-else expression. This for comprehension yields a collection with the value(s) for `z`.

Approach the problem also from the perspective of collecting transformed values,

```
e.collect {
  case x if (x == 1) => 4
  case _             => 5
}
```

even that for pattern matching two cases an if-else expression may prove more synthetic.

Comment: Out of all, that's the closest, since (my bad) I provided an example that's waaay to simplified. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can just stop thinking about for-loops in scala (because it's not a loop itself, but a for-comprehension) and use scala collections in a functional way. So for your task you can write code like this:

```
val x = List(1,2,3,4)
x.find(_ == 1).map(_ => 4).getOrElse(5)
```

Comment: In fact, Scala transforms for-comprehension statements into compositions of `map`, `flatMap`, `withFilter` and `foreach`

Comment: Right, but people moving from Java typically cannot stop thinking with plain old loops for any algorithmic task.

Answer (score 0):

You could yield a value from within the for comprehension

```
def someMethod() {
    val z = for( x <- e) {
        if(x == 1)  yield 4
        else yield 5
    }
    z
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `val z` is not necessary you can just return the result of the for comprehension.

```
def someMethod() {
    for( x <- e) {
        if(x == 1)  yield 4
        else yield 5
    }
}
```